# Expression Engine Documentation on Stackoverflow Documentation project

Tags: discussion, support

I notice when I visited SO just now I was invited to be the first to commit to the Stackoverflow Documentation project for EE.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/expressionengine/commit

I wonder if this is something the EE SE is in favor of and if so whether something can/should be done to promote it on this site.

Comment: Stack Overflow Documentation has been shut down.